# Как вставить код перед закрывающим тэгом BODY?

Tags: drupal, php

Как вставить код перед закрывающим тэгом BODY? Вставляют код через админку в разделе "Блоки" в подвал, но код вставляется не перед закрывающим BODY, а гораздо выше, оборачиваясь дополнительными дивами.

Можно ли вставить код через админку перед BODY? Если нет, то можно ли это сделать другими методами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле html.tpl.php

Comment: А в какой папке он находится?

Comment: Если его нет в папке темы, то идём в /modules/system/, находим html.tpl.php и копируем его в папку темы.

Comment: Да, в папке темы нет. Спасибо.